# My Tab in html keeps going back to the default when i submit my form

Tags: javascript, html, css

so when i press submit on my form in my 2nd tab, it automatically goes to the first tab, I would like it if possible for it to stay on the 2nd tab as i'm not able to view my information. Thank you.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        /* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        /* Style tab links */
        .tablink {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            font-size: 17px;
            width: 50%;
        }

        .tablink:hover {
            background-color: #777;
        }

        /* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
        .tabcontent {
            color: white;
            display: none;
            padding: 100px 20px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #Metric {
            background-color: royalblue;
        }

        #Imperial {
            background-color: mediumseagreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Metric', this, 'royalblue')" id="defaultOpen">Metric BMR Calculator</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Imperial', this, 'mediumseagreen')" id="defaultOpen">Imperial BMR Calculator</button>

    <div id="Metric" class="tabcontent">
        <form><br>
            <label>Sex </label>
            <select id="sex">
                <option value="M">Male</option>
                <option value="F">Female</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Age: <input type="text" id="Age" /><br><br>
            Your Height: <br>
            <br>
            Centimeters: <input type="text" id="cm" />
            <br>
            <br>
            
            Your Weight: <br>
            <br>
            Kilograms: <input type="text" id="kg" /> 
            
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="radio"  id="id1" name="fit" value="1.2" checked  >
            <label for="id1" >I am sedentary (little or no excercise)</label><br>
            <input type="radio"  id="id2"name="fit" value="1.375" >
            <label for="id2" >I am lightly active (light excercise or sports 1-3 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio"  id="id3" name="fit" value="1.55">
            <label for="id3">I am moderately active (moderate excercise or sports 3-5 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="id4" name="fit" value="1.725">
            <label for="id4">I am very active (hard excercise or sports 6-7 days per week</label><br>
            <input type="radio"  id="id5" name="fit" value="1.9">
            <label for="id5">I am super active (very hard excercise or sports and a physical job or 2x training)</label><br><br>


            <input type="submit"  onclick="metricCalculation()" /><br>
<br>

        </form>

    </div>

    <div id="Imperial" class="tabcontent">


        <form><br>
            <label>Sex </label>
            <select id="sex">
                <option value="M">Male</option>
                <option value="F">Female</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Age: <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age" /><br><br>
            Your Height: <br>
            Feet: <input type="text" id="Feet" name="Feet" />
            Inches: <input type="text" id="Inches" name="Inches" /><br><br>
            Your Weight: <br>
            Stones: <input type="text" id="Stones" /> Pounds: <input type="text" id="Pounds"><br><br>


            <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30" >
            <label for="age1">I am sedentary (little or no excercise)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="60">
            <label for="age2">I am lightly active (light excercise or sports 1-3 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
            <label for="age3">I am moderately active (moderate excercise or sports 3-5 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
            <label for="age3">I am very active (hard excercise or sports 6-7 days per week</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
            <label for="age3">I am super active (very hard excercise or sports and a physical job or 2x training)</label><br><br>


            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="imperialCalculation()" /><br>
        </form>

     


   

    </div>

    </body>

<script>
    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it


    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    
    
     function metricCalculation() {
        
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("Metric");
 
        var Age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
        var Sex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
        var Cm = document.getElementById("cm").value;
      
        var Kg = document.getElementById("kg").value;
      
        
     var activity =    document.querySelector('input[name="fit"]:checked').value;
         
      

         
    if(Sex === "M"){
        
         theDiv.innerHTML += ("male!<br>");
        
                   var total1 = (10 * Kg) + (6.25 * Cm) - (5 * Age) + 5
      
        var total2 = total1*activity;
        
        theDiv.innerHTML += ("Your BMR is: " +total1+ " Calories/Day<br>");
         
         theDiv.innerHTML +=("Your daily caloric intake should be: " + total2+ " Calories/Day<br>");
        
            }
         
          if(Sex === "F"){
              
              theDiv.innerHTML += ("female!<br>");
              
              var total1 = (10 * Kg) + (6.25 * Cm) - (5 * Age) - 161
              
               var total2 = total1*activity;
        
        theDiv.innerHTML += ("Your BMR is: " +total1+ " Calories/Day<br>");
         
         theDiv.innerHTML +=("Your daily caloric intake should be: " + total2+ " Calories/Day<br>");
              
          }

       
        
    }

   
    
     function imperialCalculation() {
        var Age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
        var LastName = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
        var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
        var Sex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML("<h1>Data Received</h1><br>");
        document.writeln("Form Completed<br><br>");
        document.writeln("The first name you entered is <b>" + FirstName + "</b><br>");
        document.writeln("The last name you entered is <b>" + LastName + "</b><br>");
        document.writeln("The email address is <b>" + Email + "</b><br>");
        document.writeln("Your sex is: " + Sex)

        document.getElementById('spanResult1').textContent = "hi";
        document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent = "cool";


    }
    

   



    function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
</script>
    
   </html>
```

I'm assuming it has to do with the "defaultOpen" id, but i'm not sure how to make it so it doesn't always go to the default opened tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `event.preventDefault()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). You need to change `imperialCalculation()` to take the parameter `event`, then call `event.preventDefault()`. Like this:

```js
function imperialCalculation(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
    // rest of function is the same
    // ...
}
```

The default behavior of a `<form>` tag is to reload the page, so form data can be sent to a server. Your form doesn't have a `action` attribute so it doesn't send anything to a server, but the browser will still reload the page. Calling `event.preventDefault()` stops the default behavior.

Comment: Thank you!!! Exactly what i needed, i put the method at the beginning of the imperial function. Now to alter all the information.... hopefully my submit button still works

Comment: hmm, for some reason, when i test my submit button, there is no following text. Oh and yes i will, there's a time limit on my end.

Comment: Ah i got it, you rock bro upvoting now.